# How to change slack notification in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, slack

I have 'Slack Notification Plugin' installed in Jenkins.
It configured to notify when Build fails or Build success.
For example with such a message:

```
jenkins BOT [9:00 PM]  
----------------
web-services tests - #58 Success after 1 min 38 sec (</job/web-services%20tests/58/|Open>)
```

Is it possible to customize message? I want to have something like this:

```
jenkins BOT [9:00 PM]  
----------------
web-services tests - #58 Success after 1 min 38 sec (USER_NAME)
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use jenkins 2.0 you can change massage something like this:

```
slackSend color: 'good', message: 'Message from Jenkins Pipeline'
```

Or something like this in UI

[image]

Comment: thank you.I am new in it where to type : slackSend color: 'good', message: 'Message from Jenkins Pipeline'   ????.

Comment: This is a part of Pipelinescript in Jenkinsfile

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/jenkinsfile/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jenkinsfile and every configuration will be in your vcs.

```
node {
    try {
        notifyStarted()
        stage 'Checkout'
        sh gg

        stage 'Build'
        sh xx

        stage 'Deploy'
        sh yy

        notifySuccessful()
    } catch(e) {
        currentBuild.result = "FAILED"
        notifyFailed()
    }
}

def notifyStarted() {
    slackSend (color: '#FFFF00', message: "STARTED: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]' (${env.BUILD_URL})")
}

def notifySuccessful() {
    slackSend (color: '#00FF00', message: "SUCCESSFUL: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]' (${env.BUILD_URL})")
}

def notifyFailed() {
  slackSend (color: '#FF0000', message: "FAILED: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]' (${env.BUILD_URL})")
}
```